# changing view's model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to change the model of a modal dialog view in backbone.js and well... no luck so far.

Here's my code:

```js
var modal,
    myCollection;

var MyModal = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: _.template($('#modalTemplate').html()),
        initialiaze: function (options) {
            this.$el = options.el;
            this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        },
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        },
        events: {
            'click .close-modal': 'closeModal'
        },
        openModal: function (model) {
            this.model.set(model);
          
            $('.modals').removeClass('hidden').fadeIn();
        },
        closeModal: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.$el.addClass('hidden');
        }
    });

var GridView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $('#grid'),
        template: _.template($('#template1').html()),
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.options = options;
            this.render();
        },
        events: {
            'click div.grid': 'openGridGallery'
        },
        openGridGallery: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            modal.openModal(myCollection.at(0));
        },
        render: function () {
            myCollection = new Backbone.Collection(this.model.get([0]));
            // ......

            modal = new MyModal({ model: new Backbone.Model(), el: $('.modals') });
            $('.modals').append(modal.render());
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="modals"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="modalTemplate">
    <div id="mymodal" class="modal">
        <div class="close"><a href="#"><span class="close-modal icon-close"></span></a></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

This works as far as creating a modal dialog and displaying it. However, this.model.set(model); inside the openModal method doesn't seem to do anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Could you change your code snippet that it will work and explain more in details what you want achieve with it?

Comment: Basically it's a grid of images and when you click on any image, it should open a modal overlay with a larger version of that image with some caption. Thanks

Comment: Your modal shows the same model because of `openGridGallery` function. `modal.openModal(myCollection.at(0))` will always show the first model in the collection. I will suggest you to move "modal open" logic to modal's view, and there handle it, to be sure which model you are showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set method of model expects the arguments to be `JSON` so try this

```
 this.model.set(model.toJSON());
```

Comment: This worked as far as updating the model but does not trigger this.model.on('change', this.render, this);

Comment: everything works now but I still don't know why this.model.on('change', this.render, this); is not being triggered. Although I can get around it by just adding this.render(); to openModal.

Comment: @petermk try setting default values in model to get the change event triggered

Answer (score 0):

In the render function of `GridView`, you should pass `new Backbone.Model()`. Also, you should convert the model to JSON before setting it as said by @aktiv-coder

```
render: function () {
  //...
  modal = new MyModal({ model: new Backbone.Model(), el: $('.modals') });
  $('.modals').append(modal.render());
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I did correct that in my code, just forgot to edit it here.

Comment: Can you correct all the mistakes in the code you posted above?